# "What kind of a person" vs. "what kind of person"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, articles, indefinite-articles

I often hear people saying *what kind of [singular noun]* rather than *what kind of **a** [singular noun]*.

Are we not supposed to use an article (*a*) before noun?

Answer (score 4):

Thinking in depth about it, either could be considered correct (i.e. neither is positively incorrect), and both are common.  It's true that an article should often be used before a noun.  Hence the following is incorrect:

> I accidentally jogged the arm of person walking by.

It should be:

> I accidentally jogged the arm of **a** person walking by.

Or, if you have already been introduced to that person:

> I accidentally jogged the arm of **the** person walking by.

However, since phrases like *what kind* are referring to a *type*, not an *individual*, the article *a* is not mandatory.  Consider the phrase *what kind of dog*.  *Dog* is a type here, not a specific dog.

Comment: On what basis do you say *what kind of person* is "the correct" form, with the implication there's something incorrect/less correct about including an article? I know the latter has always been less common (not so markedly a century or two ago), but I can't see there's any principle of grammar involved there. It goes the other way with some nouns anyway (compare *What kind of climate* with *What kind of **a** climate*), and I doubt you could set a "cut-off" point to say which nouns "need" an article in this construction.

Comment: I've just edited so as to remove my tentative hypothesis, but unfortunately I can't come up with a convincing reasoning why *what kind of a* is definitely grammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I offer as supporting evidence the song 'What Kind Of Fool Am I?'

Comment: @Daniel: You have my upvote simply for the revised answer (since I can no longer find anything to carp at!). I just came up with *"climate"* off the top of my head, but I'd have to say I agree with the majority of writers in Google Books that an article is "better" there. Perhaps some other (countable) noun would illustrate that preference even more markedly, and might guide us towards some underlying principle.

Comment: The conclusion that *a* isn't mandatory for the type makes sense, but you've failed to account for why it's not plural.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+kind+of+man%2Cwhat+kind+of+a+man%2Cwhat+kind+of+answer%2Cwhat+kind+of+an+answer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20answer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20answer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0) ...

Comment: suggest that the anarthrous versions are used but less commonly than those containing an article.

Answer (score 2):

The question form complicates this problem. Let's start by looking at `this kind of X` and `these kinds of X`. There seems to be some sort of concord between the number of the determiner (i.e., *this/these*) and the number of X. That is, you would expect *this kind of cow* or *these kinds of cows* but *this kind of cows* is rare and maybe even ungrammatical for some people, even though logically, *cows* would make sense since it is commonly used when referring to the general group (e.g., *cows give milk*). Consider also *cows of this kind* not **cow of this kind.*

This concord suggests that the determiner for *kind* is bleeding through and filling the determiner slot for X too, which is why the noun in X can be singular without needing a determiner as other singular countable nouns typically do.

Going back to the original question, I think when people say *what kind of cow,* they take *what* to fill the obligatory determiner slot for *cow* and the *kind of* becomes somewhat transparent. At some level, they are asking *what cow.* This would be somewhat analogous to the subject-verb agreement in cases like *what kind of cows **were** used* (cf. *what kind of cows **was** used*).

Those who focus on *kind*, may be more prone to see the determiner slot for X as unfilled and fill it with *a*, just as they may force number agreement between *kind* and *was* in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the intent of the question.

If you are asking about the type or group of a person, then you may skip the article: "What kind of person dress in sarong to go to work?". Although in this case, I would use *people* instead of *person*.

If you are asking about the character of the (specific) person in question, then I think the article is needed, e.g. "What kind of a person who would do such heinous thing to a puppy?"

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: If the article doesn't improve the clarity of a question ("what kind of man would. . .?" vs. "what kind of a man would . . .?), the article is unnecessary, which to me makes it more a colloquialism or idiom than a grammatical defect.