# that adjective [of] a noun

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, big-mess-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem)

I was recently typing along on this site, when I found myself typing

> . . . that big [of] a list.

and I couldn't figure out if *of* belonged in the phrase. Does it?

Comment: Also see vaguely-related [What kind of a person vs what kind of person](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61408),

Comment: @jwpat7, the second one. Thanks; I couldn't figure out how to search for it.

Comment: After I put `+of` in the search box and got no results, I clicked below "Alternately, try your search in Google:" at the bottom of the search page, and then in google changed `+of` to `"big of a"`.

Answer (score 1):

No: it's **that big a list**.

> That big a list is going to be difficult to manage.
>   A list that big is going to be difficult to manage.

I can't think of an instance where an adjective can be *of* anything.

Comment: Or, perhaps even better, _Such a big list will be difficult to manage._

Comment: @Andrew Leach: The only instance I can think of is the construction,"That is big of him." or "That is kind of him."

Comment: Google Books confirms many tens of thousands of people have gone in print with [that big of a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that+big+of+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Possibly by extension from the far more common [that much of a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that+much+of+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but the fact remains plenty of people use this form.

Comment: @FumbleFinger: Tens of thousands?  I'm surprised it's that big of a number... ;^)

Comment: common of a mistake